Can I apply for a job with my minimal experience?
I started learning web development about 2 months ago, learning the basics of html and css. I have not gotten to a point where a lot of javascript is being used yet, and I do have knowledge of basic programming concepts but the small little tutorial projects I've been following have yet to use any. Most of them also used bootstrap to handle the heavy lifting with styling.
If I continue learning for the next, say 2-3 months, would it be reasonable for me to apply for some junior level jobs?
Would it even be enough if all I had was html/css/js/bootstrap knowledge?
I am self-studying and not enrolled in any type of courses, I also plan to learn angular at some point because that is what I find on most of the job adverts in my area.
I need some advice on whats other steps you suggest I could take that would improve my chances of successfully applying and landing a job on this area.

This reminded me of my English teacher (I'm not a native speaker) and when someone asked "Can I go to the bathroom?" ... She would answer "I don't know, can you?"... in other words, yes you can. Grab your info, apply to a job, submit and ta da, you have applied to a job.... yes, will you get it? We don't know and we can't guess that answer. One seldom gets a job on the first application, so keep you options open, and of course, keep learning... that being said, Welcome to The Workplace, please read the [tour] and the [help/dont-ask] to better learn your ways around here.

After you read those things you'll notice that what you ask is off-topic for this site, as it lacks a real actionable goal (basically you ask for a yes/no answer currently), and other things. Perhaps try to reconsider a way to rephrase what you want. I may me wrong on this suggestion but for example: "I have my doubts if I'm going to be able to successfully apply and land a job right now. What steps and preparations can I take to improve my chances to land one?"... or something similar. If you see this phrasing has something we can work on and suggest and advice

That being said, I'll take a shot at editing this post. I may not hit the "spot" 100% accurately, so please enhance and edit anything you feel reflects your reality and your real question better.

I would suggest you go for React instead of Angular.

You can always apply ifor a job. At worst, people will be annoyed that you are wasting their time. Getting a job, as others have said, is more difficult.

The problem you will face more than being able to actually do the work of an entry level job is convincing hiring managers that you are a better candidate to interview than the many 2-year, 4-year, and bootcamp graduates that are applying for the same jobs you would be applying to.
With many layoffs, tightening of budgets, more widespread use of AI for basic development, and shrinking internship opportunities, there is much higher competition for entry level positions in the industry.
Currently, based on your description, nothing in your details suggests you would be a better candidate than any of the more typical path graduates, nor would you really look any different with another 2-3 months of similar experience.
The best thing you can do to present yourself as potentially qualified and worth the risk of hiring would be to get certifications from trusted sources declaring your skills. This may be a bootcamp, AWS/Microsoft certifications, or some other types of validating proof that you are able to do what you're hoping to be paid for.

"widespread use of AI for basic development"? I still have to see that

@Helena use of AI for what an intern would often do is expected at the places I have worked in the last 5 years. YMMV but it is happening.

@Helena : even if it wasn't happening, and even if it won't be happening at all for a long time, hiring managers still expect it to be happening very soon, and that will make them more reluctant to hire new people to entry-level positions.

@Forklift how many interns do you know that can be substituted by AI but do actually do enough work that it wouldn't be faster to do the work yourself instead of checking their work and teaching them? Why would you spend time on correcting AIs work if you can do it yourself just fine? AI is a tool but there seem to be a lot of people who believe that a good electrical drilling machine substitutes a good woodworker apprentice.

I will point you in a slightly different direction.
This advice is for someone with no experience and no formal education. The goal is to have a meaningful CV.
Try ideas like volunteer to help a local non-profit to help them update their web site. Keep it simple.
It is amazing how much a few hours of work will help a small non-profit that doesn't have a budget for a professional dev. It also gives you a portfolio to show off.
Join a developers group and network. Hopefully find a mentor.
Do these type of things and keep learning. It helps build some experience and shows some initiative to future employers.
You can always apply to a job. Having something on a CV that helps you stand out to a potential employer will help your chances.

Get a college degree in CS/CE
As an experienced developer with over a decade under my belt and having interviewed quite a few entry level developers, you can but not sure it’s your best strategy. If you’re in a place where you can go for a 4 year college degree in computer science or computer engineering that’s your best bet by far in terms of being attractive to prospective employers. In theory boot camps are a good secondary option, but in my experience they just don’t work and a lot of employers see right through them as basically worthless at best, a scam at worst. You simply can’t learn something as difficult as programming in a matter of a couple months to anywhere near the level to be employable. And at the end of the day what I look for in an entry level dev is someone who demonstrates understanding of programming fundamentals and the ability to learn. Add to that your self-study and you’ll have a winning package.
Bottom line: if it makes sense for where you are in life, your financial situation, etc. then it’s hard to beat a college degree in CS or CE in addition to demonstrated self study to maximize your chances at getting hired as a newbie. Don’t waste your time trying to get hired without one without significant alternative experience (e.g. as a core contributor to a major open source project), and don’t waste your time on bootcamps. They’re expensive and largely worthless.
To be very clear, I am NOT looking down on people without a college education. But there is a LOT of competition for entry-level programming jobs (in part because they pay well and in part because somehow people got the idea that anybody can program), and when you’re applying the hiring manager doesn’t know you from Adam. Your only hope statistically to land a job is to have something that convinces them you have what it takes to do one of the more intellectually challenging jobs out there, and a college degree is the easiest way by far to do that. A couple of months of basic self-study alone is not going to cut it. You’re not going to beat out the college grad who has also done self-study.
EDIT: a caveat to the above advice is the fact that with AI potentially disrupting software dev you really need to make sure whether you’re willing to make the financial and time investment needed to go to college and then attempt to get a programming job four years from now. Having worked extensively with AI I don’t see it taking any programming jobs (long term) other than those staffed by people who can’t code at all and who are trying to fake it till they make it, but short term things could get rough for those trying to enter the field. It’s hard to predict. So it’s really up to how badly you want the job. If you aren’t up for that risk, then taking a highly active role in major open source projects may be a reasonable option that has much lower risk, though also somewhat lower reward—some doors will always be closed to someone without a college degree, at least in the U.S.

“You simply can’t learn something as difficult as programming in a matter of a couple months to anywhere near the level to be employable.” - My only push back is that most college classes are only 4-5 months long and you only have 30-40 classes. The assignments are a joke, trivial assignments, that you can do after a couple hours of informal training. Programming is more of a skill, like drawing or music playing, most people can learn to do both after undergoing some basic training. The really talented can teach themselves. However, at some point, you either have a real talent or not.

100%. I didn’t want to make my answer a book so I had to cut it off at some point but college won’t teach you to program. But it will give you valuable knowledge and a stamp of approval that’s valuable if you also can code. And 100% there is a core element of talent that has to be there—a degree alone isn’t enough.

@Donald, the analogy with learning a musical instrument is a good one. If you haven't seriously engaged with music before adulthood, then you won't find waged employment as a musician with just a couple of months training on an instrument.

@Steve - I disagree you can switch to a musical career late in life, if you have the natural talent or aptitude for it, but most don’t and it’s more muscle memory for them. It would be difficult but our life’s are extremely long, so if you practice for 25 years at age 30, or practicing for 25 years at age 10. You’ll get the same amount of practice. The only difference is that 35 year old today will have 50 years of practice compared to your 25 years.

@Donald, but why would you have a natural talent for music today, but get to 30 without whistling a tune or tinkling the keys of a piano before? With machinery and information now ubiquitous, the fact that people get to adulthood now without programming skills, tends to imply something about their interests and aptitude, whereas 40 years ago it was still possible for a person with latent interest and aptitude to reach middle age with no prior access to the relevant machinery and information. (1/2)

As for learning in adulthood, the problem firstly is that middle-aged adults tend to have responsibilities, like full-time employment, maintaining a home, and family life, which draw time and energy that children have available for learning. Secondly, there is real evidence that some cognitive skills are considerably more difficult to acquire later, which is why children who are profoundly (i.e. criminally) deprived in early years often don't properly recover things like language and social skills. (2/2)


If I continue learning for the next, say 2-3 months, would it be
reasonable for me to apply for some junior level jobs?

Even junior level jobs typically require more than 5 months of self-study.
That said, read the job posting to see if you can find a job that requires no experience at all.

I am self-studying and not enrolled in any type of courses

Your burden will be to convince a hiring manager that you can perform whatever job you are applying for, with nothing demonstrable to back it up.
You would likely be competing with candidates with more experience and a degree. Try to find job openings that don't require any of these.
Good luck.

Unfortunately it's a bit like asking can you become a doctor or lawyer after 2 months of study.
True, medicine and law have guilds which enforce professional standards and completely preclude entry with so little study, but most people would understand that 2 months does not get someone anywhere near a competence in a professional occupation.
There was a time, decades ago, when employment markets were tighter, when fewer people had access to computers at home, where people with no programming experience at all would be considered as trainees for programming jobs.
This would often be on the basis of experience in other fields that were thought to leverage similar cognitive skills (including hobbies), skills as measured by employer-set tests (such as IQ tests, or data processing skills when executed on paper), or graduate-level qualifications in so-called analytical subjects (which even if you didn't become a great programmer, tended to imply a minimum of general intelligence and communication skills, enough to be useful at work and worth training).
For example, history graduates were commonly desired, because people who study history are accustomed to analysing and talking about complex subjects which involve change over time, and which involve the handling of historical records (as distinct from direct knowledge of events).
So were music graduates, because music involves analysing timing, sequencing, rhythm, and concurrent "voices" in a musical piece, and there is often a practical side of experience involving familiarity with musical machinery (including electronic instruments and equipment), and physically playing instruments (quite often co-operatively with other people, or in a band).
There was also a period, perhaps soaring from the mid 80s, when it started to become common for children and adults to have access to computers at home if they wanted one, and those so inclined could accumulate years of self-study and hobby activity at home. Bill Gates is a prime example - he was entering the employment market for programmers even earlier in the 1970s.
The widespread availability of home computers and technology means the days when non-programmers without even hobby experience could get any kind of formal training are over.
There is some degree of childhood hobby background, amounting to years (not months) of study, amongst virtually all programmers nowadays. It's very unlikely you'd get a programming job without it, and if you don't already have it, adulthood is a bad time to start trying. That's the truth.

By “the days when non-programmers without even hobby experience could get any kind of formal training are over” I assume you mean on the job training, meaning hired with no skills at all (including no CS/CE degree) and then trained 100% on the job?

@bob, yes I mean training funded by an employer, and furnished to somebody who doesn't already have a proven exposure to a programming language and a demonstrable basic competency. I'm not sure whether a person could successfully complete a CS degree with no programming competency - not because a CS course actually furnishes the skills, but because it requires self-directed practical training to occur to acquire the associated cognitive skills and fitness, which most will do before the course even commences.

Yes, but not with that level of experience
Back in the mid 2000s, I landed a well-paid contract with C+++ coding despite having no commercial experience with C++. How did I manage that?
First off, I'd been using C++ extensively on a personal project. I could talk about what I'd done, and I could breeze through their tests. It sounds like you're some distance off this.
Second off, I did have commercial experience in a related area, and in doing the kind of work they were looking for. Remember that web design isn't just the technical side. Do you have a background in graphic design? If you can mock up a great-looking site, employers may well make allowances for your current lack of technical chops.
I'd say good luck, but the reality is that you need to make your luck here.
